# How does latex source multiple configuration files..?

Tags: texmf, unix

I have got a very peculiar question I'd like to ask about my latex processor:

- In my school we are using the pdfTeXk backend. At some point there was a need to make a few configuration changes within the `/usr/share/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf` configuration file (essentially set some values).
- However since it's the school server I'm working on, I don't have root access to modify that file. Instead, we were told to create a texmf folder `~/texmf` under our home directory and put any additional packages and configuration files in there should we needed to. And so I did by creating `~/texmf/texmf.cnf` and placing my custom settings in it.

Now, the system is set to look for its configuration files using an environmental variable called `TEXMFCNF`. The default configuration location can be checked by issuing `kpsewhich texmf.cnf`. The problem is that if I set it to point to my custom configuration folder at `~/texmf` it will ignore the default one in `/usr/share/texmf/web2c` (which contains many other settings I need) and only fetch mine. The same happens the other way around.

Eventually the question is: How do I make latex fetch both of the texmf.cnf files?

---

(*This question is an exact replica of this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854289/how-does-latex-source-multiple-configuration-files and is posted here after suggestion of the user Andrea Bergia*)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Kpathsea](http://www.pd.infn.it/TeX/doc/html/kpathsea/kpathsea_3.html#SEC51) manual,

> Kpathsea reads all 'texmf.cnf' files in the search path, not just the first one found; definitions in earlier files override those in later files. Thus, if the search path is '.:$TEXMF', values from './texmf.cnf' override those from '$TEXMF/texmf.cnf'.

In the TEXMFCNF variable you can use colons to separate several paths to search for texmf.cnf files in.  An empty path entry [should correspond to](http://www.pd.infn.it/TeX/doc/html/kpathsea/kpathsea_3.html#SEC53) searching the system paths.  Thus, you should be able to set TEXMFCNF to "~/texmf/:" (with a trailing colon) to have the system use settings from your texmf.cnf, if present, and use the system settings otherwise.